# Determine the equation of the line the portion of which, intercepted by the axes, is divided by the point $(-5,4)$ in the ratio of $1:2$.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Determine the equation of the line the portion of which, intercepted by the axes, is divided by the point $(-5,4)$ in the ratio of $1:2$.

My Attempt:
Let the equation of straight line be
$$ax+by+c=0$$
It passes through the point $(-5,4)$.
$$-5a+4b+c=0$$

Comment: Personally, I would not write the equation of the line as ax+ by+ c= 0 because multiplying each of a, b, and c by the same number would give a different equation of that form for the same line.  Instead, divide through by b and write the equation as y= ax+ c.  Since it passes through (-5, 4) we have -5= 4a+ c so that c= -4- 4a and we can write the equation as y= ax- 4- 4a or y= a(x- 4)- 4.  The y-intercept is where y= 0= a(x- 4)- 4 so x= (4/a)+ 4 so ((4/a)+ 4, 0).  The x-intercept is where x= 0 so y= -4a- 4 or (0, -4a- 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the equation be $$\dfrac xa+\dfrac yb=1$$

So, $(a,0);(0,b)$ is divided in $1:2$ at $(-5,4)$

i.e., $-5=\dfrac{a\cdot2+0\cdot1}{2+1}$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: make the Ansatz $$y=mx+n$$  since $P(-5,4)$ is situated on the line we have
$$y=m(x+5)+4$$ and the intersection Point withe the $x$ axes is $$P_x(-5-\frac{4}{m};0)$$ and the y-axes  $$P_y(0;5m+4)$$
Now must $$\frac{P_xP}{PP_y}=\frac{1}{2}$$ can you finish?